# Unpack and x option in TEMPLATE

Tags: perl, templates, unpack

I have a row which looks like (no new lines, this is one line and I replaces the spaces with _ as otherwise they are trimmed):

> 46S990BZ6BRIG___1381TRANSOCEAN_LTD______________BCALL_FEB00025000__1000000000000000000000000000000000000000B90002132015000000099999900161100000000000000007500111214111414121714100003000_H8817H100015012200005000000000010000000000000000000000009920202020150213__20_________________________________________________OV__0203P

The the use of unpack perl method returns as follows:

```
unpack("x49 A4", $line); # where $line is the above example line
```

returns: CALL

```
unpack("x68 A4", $line);
```

returns: 0122

```
unpack("x238 A4", $line);
```

return: 2015

Apparently, the column numbers do not match with the number given after 'x' in the TEMPLATE, as x238 is not equal to column 238 ('0000'), I have '2015' on column 251, not 238. The same for the other.

Please, explain how exactly the numbers given after 'x' in TEMPLATE work.

Thank you

Comment: `unpack("x238 A4", $line)` returns "0000" for me with your data. Please compare the code you're running with the code you pasted.

Comment: At a guess, maybe your original data has tabs instead of sequences of spaces. A tab might visually occupy more than one *column*, but it's only one *character*.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your data isn't what you said it is. The data you provided produces the desired result.

```
$ perl -E'
   my $line = "46S990BZ6BRIG___1381TRANSOCEAN_LTD______________BCALL_FEB00025000__1000000000000000000000000000000000000000B90002132015000000099999900161100000000000000007500111214111414121714100003000_H8817H100015012200005000000000010000000000000000000000009920202020150213__20_________________________________________________OV__0203P";
   $line =~ s/_/ /g;
   say unpack("x238 A4", $line);
'
0000
```

Maybe your actual data contained non-printable characters. Or maybe some of the spaces were actually tabs.

```
$ perl -E'
   $_ = "46S990BZ6BRIG___1381TRANSOCEAN_LTD______________BCALL_FEB00025000__1000000000000000000000000000000000000000B90002132015000000099999900161100000000000000007500111214111414121714100003000_H8817H100015012200005000000000010000000000000000000000009920202020150213__20_________________________________________________OV__0203P";
   s/_/ /g;
   s/LTD\K\s+/\t\t/;  # If the spaces after LTD were tabs
   say unpack("x238 A4", $_);
'
2015
```

If you want to extract the characters at based on how your viewer expands tabs, you will need to expand tabs to spaces in the same fashion before passing the string to `unpack`.